# .editorconfig for Test projects/classes

Tags: c#, code-analysis, editorconfig

I'm using an `.editorconfig` file on a global level for the entire solution. This is working fine so far. The existing rules do work.

Now I want a rule for `VSTHRD200` for my test projects and classes, I've added the following lines:

```
# Test projects
[{IntegrationTest.*,Test.*}.csproj]
dotnet_diagnostics.VSTHRD200.severity = none # VSTHRD200: Use "Async" suffix for async methods
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.VSTHRD200.severity = none # VSTHRD200: Use "Async" suffix for async methods

# Test classes
[Test*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostics.VSTHRD200.severity = none # VSTHRD200: Use "Async" suffix for async methods
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.VSTHRD200.severity = none # VSTHRD200: Use "Async" suffix for async methods
```

These rules do work in a way, that I do not see warnings in Output window. But these rules do not apply to the `category-Style`, means I do see curly lines for test methods, which do not have a `Async` suffix in editor.

I've added `dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = none` like VS 2019 suggested and placed them under the section headers for test projects and classes, but I have the feeling, that it'll disable **all** styling rules.

Is there a way to only disable the styling for the `VSTHRD200` error code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late to the game, but for those like me who had this problem, this worked:

```
[*Test*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.VSTHRD200.severity = suggestion
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.VSTHRD200.severity = suggestion
```

The solution above was almost correct but there was an "s" to much:
dotnet_diagnostic**s**.VSTHRD200.severity = none # VSTHRD200: Use "Async" suffix for async methods

Comment: Oh no, just the small typo made it fail? Thanks for your answer!